# Sorting 2D array containing special characters C++

Tags: c++, arrays, special-characters

I would like to sort this array but this code works if I do not put any string with special characters in the array.
If I have something like

> !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@

it wont work. It crashes in Visual Studio.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    char data[10][40] = {     
      "",
      "Welcome",
      " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@",
      "aBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`",
      "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyZ{||||||||||}",
      "CD_ROM",
      "ROM",
      "SCS",
      "3.5 Floppi",
      ""
    };


    cout<<"Printing the array as is"<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            cout<<data[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl<<"Ordering the data in Alphabetical order"<<endl<<endl;


    // bubble sort

    for (int i=0 ; i<10-1 ; ++i) {
            char Tcopy[17];
            for (int j=i+1 ; j<10 ; ++j) {
                    if (strcmp(data[i], data[j]) > 0) {
                            strcpy(Tcopy, data[i]);
                            strcpy(data[i], data[j]);
                            strcpy(data[j], Tcopy);
                    }
            }
    }


    cout<<"Printing the array Sorted"<<endl<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            cout<<data[i]<<endl;
    }


// Pause
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"Please Close Console Window"<<endl;
    cin.ignore('\n', 1024);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't work?"  What output are you getting?  What output did you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by *it won't work*? Are you not getting the expected results? Does it crash? Erase your hard drive? Burn your toast? Tease your dog? Borrow your car and return it with an empty tank?

Comment: Why is your temporary string only 17 `char`s long when the data you're sorting is 40?

Comment: *Aside*: you have the parameters to `cin.ignore` reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char data[10][40]
…
char Tcopy[17];
…
strcpy(Tcopy, data[i]);
```

There's your problem. Your `Tcopy` array is too short. You are copying (potentially) 40 characters into a 17-character array. You are overwriting the end of your buffer, resulting in who-knows-what damage.

Try:

```
char Tcopy[40];
```

Comment: Hmm. [Works for me](http://ideone.com/dNSM3). What, precisely, does it do when you run it, and what do you expect it to do?